# pandas - How to get 7 day sum for groups when some groups do not have entries on all days

Tags: python, pandas

I have some data like this:

```
date, group_name, value
-------------------
2017-07-01, A, 10
2017-07-05, A, 4
2017-07-05, B, 21
```

I want to compute the rolling 7 day sum of each group but the data only for each group only has records when the value is > 0 for that day.

I want the output to look like:

```
date, group_name, value, 7d_sum_of_value
----------------------------------------
2017-07-01, A, 10, 10
2017-07-05, A, 4, 14
2017-07-05, B, 21, 21
```

Comment: How do you define each 7 days? For example, is it every 7 days starting from the start of the month, or every 7 days where each of the 7 days is within a particular week?

Comment: add those missing `index` and `groupby` `rollingsum`

Comment: @joceratops, I'm defining 7 days as the current day and previous six days.

Comment: @Wen, can you give an example with adding missing index? There's multiple columns I'm grouping by with high cardinality ~7 million unique permutations. Thanks!

Comment: `df.groupby('group_name')['value'].apply(lambda x:pd.rolling_sum(x.resample("1d"), 7, min_periods=1)).reset_index()` and `merge` with original `df` do you need me writing done as an answer ?

Comment: @Wen Yes if you could provide that example it would be much appreciated!

Comment: I posted~~ if you have any question let me know

Answer (score 1):

You can try this , but according to your `data` size (7 million), there must be some solution more efficient than mine.

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2017-07-01', '2017-07-05', '2017-07-05'], 'group_name': ['A', 'A', 'B'], 'value': [10, 4, 21]})
df.date=pd.to_datetime(df.date)
df = df.set_index('date')
df['date']=df.index

A=df.groupby('group_name')['value'].apply(lambda x:pd.rolling_sum(x.resample("1d"), 7, min_periods=1)).reset_index()

df.merge(A,left_on=['date','group_name'],right_on=['date','group_name'],how='left')



Out[201]: 
  group_name  value_x       date  value_y
0          A       10 2017-07-01     10.0
1          A        4 2017-07-05     14.0
2          B       21 2017-07-05     21.0
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [timedeltas](https://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

```
import pandas as pd
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

testdata = pd.DataFrame({'date': ['2017-07-01', '2017-07-05', '2017-07-05'], 'group_name': ['A', 'A', 'B'], 'value': [10, 4, 21]})
testdata['7d_sum_of_value'] = 0

for index1, row1 in testdata.iterrows(): # Iterate over all rows in data
    rolling_sum = row1['value'] # Initialize rolling_sum
    group_data = testdata[testdata['group_name'] == row1['group_name']] # Choose subset of data that pertains to the appropriate group
    for index2, row2 in group_data.iterrows(): 
        date_diff = datetime.strptime(row1['date'], '%Y-%m-%d')-datetime.strptime(row2['date'], '%Y-%m-%d') # Get time difference between two dates
        if (date_diff >= timedelta(0)) and (date_diff <= timedelta(7)) and (index1 != index2):
            rolling_sum += row2['value'] # Update rolling sum
    testdata.set_value(index1, '7d_sum_of_value', rolling_sum) # Insert rolling sum into data
```